# C# Tuple comparison

Tags: c#, comparison, tuples

I have been trying badly the last two days to get this part of my code to work properly.

```
foreach (Tuple<StateObject,string> tupleObj in TCP_Globals.stateObj)
{

    if (tupleObj.Item2.Equals(ConnectedClientsListView.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DEBUG #3");
        StateObject stateObj = tupleObj.Item1; //Obtain the underlying socket management class via remoteIP
        MessageBox.Show("DEBUG #4");
    }
}
```

The...

```
if (tupleObj.Item2.Equals(ConnectedClientsListView.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text))
```

...doesnt get true even if the two strings contain the same value. The if never passes. How do I compare the tuple obj with the listViewItem correctly?

Comment: Are you sure they're the same value? And both strings? Note that the `Equals` method uses an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison, so e.g. "file" and "File" are different.

Comment: I am sure them both contain the same value, also strings.

Comment: Is the `Text` property of type `string`, or something more general like `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
if (tupleObj.Item2.ToString().ToLower() == 
         ConnectedClientsListView.FocusedItem.SubItems[2].Text.ToLower())
```

EDIT:

Since you said that strings are IP's so in that case

```
var firstip = IPAddress.Parse(first_string);
var secondip = IPAddress.Parse(second_string);

if (firstip.Equals(secondip))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal!");
}
```

Comment: That is not the right way to do a case-insensitive comparison. Use an overload that takes a `StringComparison` enum, and specify one that's case-insensitive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx

Comment: Nope, still return false. The both string contain "192.168.1.66:123" a ip and port in string.

Comment: @user1906993: In that case use `IPAddress` class.

Comment: It has nothing to do with case sensitive or uppercase because it's just numbers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Now it works :) But I still do not understand why my solution don't work. Would be glad if someone could explain.

Comment: My best guess is that there really was a minor difference, that you didn't notice via whatever mechanism you were using to look. Debugging and just looking at that string there is probably the best way to check, in general, but considering the difficulties here, I'd also try getting each `byte[]` with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)` and compare them with the debugger or other output; that way you can be absolutely sure of any differences in the characters (some characters may look alike, but there's no ambiguity in bytes).